# 408 error when sending large email through Gmail API with libcurl

Tags: google-api, gmail-api

I am trying to send an email through gmail from a c++ app using libcurl to access the rest-api.

Most of the time, this works flawlessly, but with big emails (>2MB) I randomly get an oddly formatted `"Error 408 (Request Timeout)!!1"` response. The bigger the Email, the more likely these errors seem to be. At 2MB it happens about 60% of the time, with 7MB I get almost no Mails through.

I am wondering how to best debug this issue and what could cause it, as libcurl doesn't report any timeout issues and seems to successfully finish sending the email data. The error response is received about a minute after libcurl finishes sending, so it looks like the server is waiting for more data. The amount I send is in line with what I report in the "Content-length" field and I always test with exactly the same email data (which randomly works/fails).

The response is not in JSON (despite my "Accepted: application/json" header), but in somewhat minimalistic html (missing body, head tags) and reads as if it was not intended for endusers:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
  <title>Error 408 (Request Timeout)!!1</title>
  <style>
    *{margin:0;padding:0}html,code{font:15px/22px arial,sans-serif}html{background:#fff;color:#222;padding:15px}body{margin:7% auto 0;max-width:390px;min-height:180px;padding:30px 0 15px}* > body{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png) 100% 5px no-repeat;padding-right:205px}p{margin:11px 0 22px;overflow:hidden}ins{color:#777;text-decoration:none}a img{border:0}@media screen and (max-width:772px){body{background:none;margin-top:0;max-width:none;padding-right:0}}#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;margin-left:-5px}@media only screen and (min-resolution:192dpi){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat 0% 0%/100% 100%;-moz-border-image:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) 0}}@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;-webkit-background-size:100% 100%}}#logo{display:inline-block;height:54px;width:150px}
  </style>
  <a href=//www.google.com/><span id=logo aria-label=Google></span></a>
  <p><b>408.</b> <ins>That’s an error.</ins>
  <p>Your client has taken too long to issue its request.  <ins>That’s all we know.</ins>
```

I am sending my `message/rfc822` data to the endpoint at
https://www.googleapis.com/upload/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/send
and have tried both, using *Simple* and *Resumable* upload flows.

The only way I found to improve the situation is to reduce the amount of data that libcurl sends at a time, but this seems to only make the issue less likely, not to avoid it completely.
Sending the HTTP-request with 1000 bytes at a time seems to make the issue almost disappear...

Comment: please edit your question and include your code.   However there isnt much you can do but retry if it timed out.

Comment: I tried to find a concise code snippet I could post here, but the code is spread over several files, including a c++ wrapper for libcurl and some general REST-API abstraction... I will see if I can reproduce the issue with curl on the command line and post a shell script.

Edited the post to say that the timeout happens over 50% of the time, so with retrying, it might take minutes to successfully send a mail (at least at default curl settings).